# Passing request as a parameter to a function

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-mobile-services

In my custom Azure API, I want to pass request as a parameter to a function.  From that function I want to be able to access query parameters and also use service.mssql to execute a query on my database.  However request.query.fieldName is coming up null within the function.

```
exports.post = function(request, response) {
console.log("passed UserID = " + request.query.UserID);
request.service.mssql.query(query, {
    success: function(results) {
    if (foo) {
        callFunction(results[0], request);
    }
});

function callFunction(firstResult, request) {
    console.log("UserID received in function = " + request.query.UserID);
}
```

In my console I see:

```
Error   Error in script '/api/testapi.js'. TypeError: Cannot read property 'UserID' of undefined
```

Is there something special about request that means it can't be passed to a new function?

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to see some documentation to this effect, but it appears that the variables request and response must be the first two passed to the function if they're to work correctly.  This code will work:

```
exports.post = function(request, response) {
console.log("passed UserID = " + request.query.UserID);
request.service.mssql.query(query, {
    success: function(results) {
    if (foo) {
        callFunction(request, response, results[0]);
    }
});

function callFunction(request, response, firstResult) {
    console.log("UserID received in function = " + request.query.UserID);
}
```